# Why doesn't exec sp_recompile sometimes not help parameter sniffing?

Tags: sql-server-2017

We have a complex stored procedure that is sometimes subject to parameter sniffing. It is a large, "all-in-one" procedure that is called by many different parts of the system and so it stands to reason that one query plan would not fit all use cases.

This works fine except periodically ONE particular report goes from seconds to minutes. In the past, a quick `exec sp_recompile` would speed it back up immediately. Now that never works. The report just eventually "fixes itself" in a day or two, meaning it goes back to taking seconds.

Refactoring the stored procedure is currently not an option and I don't want to do the other recommended approaches (saving parameters to local variables, WITH RECOMPILE, OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) as those are said to have other side effects.

So I have these questions:

1. Why wouldn't `exec sp_recompile` speed it up like before?
2. How can I tell if `exec sp_recompile` actually cleared the query plan cache? What should be run before, and after, the exec? I've tried some queries from the web but can't clearly tell if something changed, so a specific recipe would be great to have.
3. Would it be reasonable to clone the procedure with a different name, and call that clone just for this one report? The goal would be to get SQL Server to cache a separate plan just for the report. But I'm not sure if SQL Server is caching plans by procedure name, or if it caches the various queries inside the stored procedures. (If it's the latter, then there's no use to this approach, as the any clones of the procedure would have the same queries.)

Comment: Is this procedure composed of multiple queries with procedural programming or just one big query fitting al cases?

Comment: What does "like before" mean - before what exactly?

Comment: @Alejandro it's a little bit of preparatory code to set some variables, then a WITH t1 AS q1 t2 AS q2 t3 AS q3 ... SELECT ... FROM (joins of the t1, t2...). Some of the "WITH" queries are fairly large, one of them is immense.  Someone wrote it long ago, it has worked flawlessly for years, it performs several important functions, and nobody wants to touch it... Joel On Code's advice on the "rewrite trap"seems particularly relevant here.  :-)

Comment: @Stu  So last year we figured out this behavior was due to parameter sniffing and if the report ran slow we just ran "exec sp_recompile" on the stored procedure, and the report ran fast again. That would be around once a month. Now even if we do the recompile, the report is still slow, but after a day or two it again goes back to normal speed. So somehow the query cache - if that is the problem - resets itself, but no longer immediate when doing 'exec sp_recompile'.

Comment: Possibly the parameters used immediately after the recompile are also problematic? "Why wouldn't exec sp_recompile speed it up like before?" Impossible to know without the queries, the tables and indexes, the good and bad query plans, the relevant parameters and how they fit in with the table statistics/histogram. All of which you should be doing, not us, as it's info that you have. If you are not prepared to rewrite anything you won't get very far: using `sp_recompile` is a hack, be prepared for it to fail

Comment: If you have a lot of CTE definitions used, SQL Server will be attempting to construct a single monolithic execution plan. It's possible, depending on varying factors, you have a plan compilation timeout and a sub-optimal plan, for which recompiling yields the same - or worse. You could instead replace the CTEs with temp tables - using intermediate results often has better performance as each query executes in isolation with a dedicated optimal (or better) plan. These can then be further clustered to remove intermediate sorts in the main query and allow the optimizer to use statistics too.

Comment: How often is the proc executed? If not many times per second, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` may be a good option as the runtime savings with an optimal plan may more than offset the side effect of additional compilation costs. I've had good success with that approach for kitchen sink queries.

Comment: @Charlieface indeed the parameters used from somewhere else (the SP is called from many places) may be bad for the report. I agree with everything you said, but I am asking a specific question (#3), a technical question about MSSQL. Can I clone the stored procedure and call it from the report, and expect MSSQL to prepare a separate plan for the queries in the cloned procedure? Or will not that work because the queries in the cloned procedure are the same as the original?

Comment: @Stu That's definitely an easier approach to refactoring, as it would avoid tinkering with the actual query logic.  Thank you, it's a great tool to have if cloning the stored procedure won't help. Do you have thoughts on that, my question #3?

Comment: @royappa cloning the procedure I believe should give you a separately compiled execution plan each execution plan is compiled per unique hash of the statement text; if you change the statement, even comments (I believe) you get a new hash and a new plan.

Comment: @DanGuzman So at some times of the day the procedure is called hundreds of times over the course of a couple hours, from one part of the C# code. And then this report, which uses the procedure differently (in the sense that a very different slice of the data is returned) is called 2-3 times a day. So the first type of call and the second type of call will probably need different plans. That's why I'm asking my question #3 - can I just clone the procedure to a different name and get totally different plans cached for the same queries, because they are under different procedure names now.

Comment: @Stu wow that would be fantastic. Any pointers to documentation that would confirm it? The problem is that we cannot reproduce on our test system (which is a copy of the production database - once you copy the database, the problem goes away). It only shows up in the production system due to its pattern of usage. And since this requires a code change and new software deployment, it would be nice to "KNOW" instead of deploying a software change and waiting. But your opinion definitely gives me hope. Should I ask this specific question on the DBA stackexchange?

Comment: @Stu anyway, can you please reply to my question with "A. Refactor CTE's with temp tables and B. The procedure cloning probably creates a separate plan". I would like to accept that as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @royappa, that execution frequency is small enough not to be a concern with the query hint, IMHO.  That would require no other code changes and you'll probably get better plans across the board.

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you. We would have used WITH RECOMPILE on the stored procedure but Brent Ozar's site spoke of a rare bug with that, and he is not 100% confident it is truly fixed. So I'm trying to avoid the query hint approach even though that would be very convenient.

Comment: @royappa, to be clear, I mean the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint, not the the proc option (which is a bit heavy-handed).

Comment: @DanGuzman I didn't catch the distinction, so thanks for confirming. OK, OPTION(RECOMPILE) hint on the kitchen-sink query (good term) inside the stored procedure, versus WITH RECOMPILE on the procedure as a whole. I will keep that as another tool if the "clone stored procedure" doesn't work, very useful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using several CTEs, especially complex queries (just like when joining with views) can potentially cause the query optimiser problems with producing an optimal execution plan.

If you have a lot of CTE definitions used, SQL Server will be attempting to construct a single monolithic execution plan and you could have a plan compilation timeout resulting in a sub-optimal plan being used.

You could instead replace the CTEs with temp tables - using intermediate results often has better performance as each query executes in isolation with a dedicated optimal (or at least better) plan. This can help the optimizer make a better choice for joins and index usage.

If you can benefit from two key different types of parameters that ideally require their own optimal plan then an option would be, as you suggest, to duplicate the procedure specific to each use-case.

You can confirm that this results in a separate execution plan by querying for your procedure name using `dm_exec_sql_text`

```
select s.plan_handle, t.text
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats s 
cross apply Sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.plan_handle)t 
where t.text like '%proc name%'
```

You will note you have a different *plan_handle* for each procedure.

Comment: Accepted as it provides a great alternate suggestion, confirmation of question #3 and a specific recipe to test for two different plans being created. Thank you.